# How to achieve a disabled look on a Text composable

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to recreate a Preferences screen in Compose but I'm not sure what's the best way to implement the disabled state of an item.

Here is an example of the disabled state:

[image]

With the old `TextView` I can easily use the method `setEnabled()`, that will take care for me to disable click listeners and change the textColor.
The `Text()` composable doesn't seem to implement this feature so, I was wondering if there is an easy way to achieve the same result.

Ideally, I would like find an easy way to get the default disabled color or the default alpha to apply to the current text color to achieve the disabled look.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`ContentAlpha.disabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/ContentAlpha#disabled()).

To apply it for a bunch of views, you can provide [`LocalContentAlpha`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#LocalContentAlpha()):

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalContentAlpha provides if (enabled) ContentAlpha.high else ContentAlpha.disabled,
) {
    Text("title", color = Color.DarkGray.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current))
    Text("subtitle", color = Color.LightGray.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current))
}
```

Note that in order for `LocalContentAlpha` and `LocalContentColor` to work, your `Text` `color` and `style.color` parameters should be `Color.Unspecified` (this is the default value). If you're specifying it directly, you can apply `ContentAlpha.disabled` manually:

```
Text(
    "your text",
    color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
    // or if you're using colored style
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.let { style ->
        style.copy(color = style.color.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled))
    },
    // or just apply alpha modifier to the view
    modifier = Modifier.alpha(ContentAlpha.disabled)
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks! But I think that it will be tricky to deal with disabled state using `LocalContentAlpha`: I'm already using it to set the subtitle to `ContentAlpha.medium` what I would like to achieve is to apply the `ContentAlpha.disabled` on top of the `ContentAlpha.medium`, otherwise the title and subtitle will end up with the same color when disabled. If you look at the screenshot I posted, the subtitle of an item is lighter in color than the title, even when the item is disabled.

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi You won't have such problem if use non alpha colors for your enabled text. You can provide it for each text with `LocalContentColor`, in this case `LocalContentAlpha` will be applied to them. An other option is applying alpha directly, see updated answer

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure if is the best: instead of changing the color of the text, I'm changing the alpha of the entire composable using the `Modifier` and setting the alpha to the value defined in `ContentAlpha.disabled`:

```kotlin
val alpha = if (enabled) 1f else ContentAlpha.disabled
Text(
    modifier = Modifier
        .alpha(alpha = alpha)
        .clickable(enabled = enabled) { onClick() },
    text = "Lorem ipsum",
)
```

Answer (score 4):

In [Material3](https://m3.material.io/) you can use the alpha of the [LocalContentColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#LocalContentColor()).

```
      CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides
          if (enabled) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
          else MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.38f)
      ) {
        Text(text = "Lorem ipsum")
        // if you want a different color for one text
        Text(
          text = "Lorem ipsum different color",
          color = Color.Magenta.copy(alpha = LocalContentColor.current.alpha)
        )
      }
```

See the [official migration guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material2-material3#emphasis-and) for more information